# Handling Redirects with axios in Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, npm, axios

How to handle the redirects in axios so as to obtain the redirected URL within the browser, during an API call?

I need to get the **url after redirection** using *GET*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This isn't currently possible in the browser but is in Node. If you are using node you can access the url after redirection in

```
response.request.res.responseUrl
```

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/799

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for in browser. Might have been more useful if they could implement that too.